# Find passwords values in JSON objects using Regex

Tags: java, arrays, json, regex, passwords

I have a big JSON object which contains a lot of different JSON, most of them have the structure below (key: sometext-v1.password, and value: password
for example:

```
"apps":[
        "settings": [
                    {
                       "name" : "sometext-v1.password-v1",
                       "value" : "myPassword"
                    },
                    ...
                    ...
```

I want to use Regex to extract all passwords by a name which contains 'password' string and its value, but I don't want to iterate the JSON name by name because this takes a lot of time for processing.

I tried this, but it isn't working:

```
String regex = "\"*password*\":\\s*\".*?\"";
```

Comment: You need to check for `password` in a *name* value, and then grab the `value` value. Use  `String regex = "\"name\"\\s*:\\s*\"[^\"]*password[^\"]*\",\\s*\"value\"\\s*:\\s*\"([^\"]*)";`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/feHDVr/1).

Comment: Why not? [Looks working to me](https://ideone.com/IOUlt0). Are you sure you have the string you shared?

Comment: Ok thanks you very much, that's working after converting to java string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```java
String regex = "\"name\"\\s*:\\s*\"[^\"]*password[^\"]*\",\\s*\"value\"\\s*:\\s*\"([^\"]*)";
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/feHDVr/1). Details:

- `"name"` - a literal string
- `\s*:\s*` - a `:` enclosed with optional whitespaces
- `"` - a `"` char
- `[^"]*password[^"]*` - `password` enclosed with 0 or more chars other than a `"`
- `",`  - a `",` string
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `"value"`  - a literal text
- `\s*:\s*` - a `:` enclosed with optional whitespaces
- `"` - a `"` char
- `([^"]*)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than `"`.

See a Java demo:

```java
String s = "\"apps\":[\n        \"settings\": [\n                    {\n                       \"name\" : \"sometext-v1.password-v1\",\n                       \"value\" : \"myPassword\"\n                    },\n                    ...";
String regex = "\"name\"\\s*:\\s*\"[^\"]*password[^\"]*\",\\s*\"value\"\\s*:\\s*\"([^\"]*)";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(s);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
// => myPassword
```